# Integrating and using a legacy Mysql DB in Django Application

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

This is my first question on this site and I am new to Django, SQL and development in general.  So here goes nothing!

Operating system - Mac OS X 10.10.5.

1. I am building an app using Django v 1.8.  The specific within the project will be quite simple -  it will perform queries against an *existing* MySQL database.
2. I am currently using MySQL v5.6.27 (with MySQLworkbench 6.3) and had it installed in its default location.

   ```
   /usr/local/var/mysql
   ```
3. I went to painstaking lengths to populate this database with a great deal of data using a python script.  The database is something crucial for the project and something I want to query using my django app.
4. Next, I configure my settings.py file within my project to use mysql instead of the default sqlite that comes it it.

   ```
   projectroot/projectname/settings.py

   DATABASES = {
     'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'APP_stock_data',   #Name of the DB I have my data in
       'USER': 'User',
       'PASSWORD': 'my-pw',  #Changed for this post
       'HOST': 'localhost',   
       'PORT': '',
     }
   }
   ```

**Question/Request:**

Here is what I have been attempting to do with no luck:

- The MySQL database has a ton of data.  I want to ship that Database with the Django app.  How do I get the mySQL database into my Django app? Do I do a mysql dump and dump the data into a database directory? (such as the example below)

  ```
  /projectroot/database
  ```
- I also want to the ability to make new tables so I can make users models, new posts etc.  The plan was simply to create new models within each application via migrations.  Can I simply make normal migrations to this database once it is in the directory listed above without effecting the integrity of the existing data?

Answer (score 0):

Use django `inspectdb` command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

This will export all database tables to models classes. However you need to connect to the old database first, but this command won't touch the database records but just read the schema.

If you just want to continue using your original database, then that's it. Otherwise you can dump the sql to a file and import it into your new database. In the end you just need to configure your django to point to the right database.

Django has doc that explains [how to integrate with legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: Exactly right -  I was able to successfully export the schemas just as you had suggested and dump them into a model.py file ( this wont be needed for this app since its only reading the data).

Comment: And thanks for the heads up on dumping the file into the right directory.  Being somewhat new , even simple concepts such as this are still a "work in progress"

Comment: Yea, dumping/loading data might take time and resource from your server, but just do it once won't hurt. Have you tried to check how big is your database? How many records does it hold?

Comment: Dumping and loading this data only needs to be done once - I do not intend to write to this DB  unless I update the actual data base which will be done quarterly.  The main table with all the data is approximately 500 mb and has about 1.3 million rows.